# Exit / break promise using custom error

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm looking for an easier / simpler way to create an error function, I'm simply looking for an easy way to exit a promise chain. Below you can see an error object `NoUserFound` and a promise chain. The desired result I'm looking for is when `model.readUserAddresses` returns `false` I throw a specific error to skip over the promise chain. Is there a simpler more straight-forward (one-line) way to create a `NoUserFound` custom error just for this purpose?

```
function NoUserFound(value) {
   Error.captureStackTrace(this);
   this.value = value;
   this.name = "NoUserFound";
}
NoUserFound.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);

model.readUserAddresses(email)
  .then(ifFalseThrow(NoUserFound))
  .then(prepDbCustomer)
  .then(shopify.customerCreate)
  .catch(NoUserFound, () => false)
```

Ideally I can just do something like this.

```
model.readUserAddresses(email)
  .then(ifFalseThrow('NoUserFound'))
  .then(prepDbCustomer)
  .then(shopify.customerCreate)
  .catch('NoUserFound', () => false)
```

And not have to have a useless one-time error class.

Comment: Thinking, it might be best if this first promise in chain threw actual error.

Comment: im not sure about the Current implementation of Promises in Native but it is implemented well in [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) where you can make a customize error for the promises

Comment: `function ifFalseThrow(e){return function(v){if(!v) throw new Error(e)}}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756903/bluebird-js-custom-error-catch-function-does-not-apply-on-the-first-promise

Comment: Have you considered implementing Promise.reject() in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to build your own error class, you can also use one of [Bluebird's builtin error types](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/built-in-error-types.html), namely an [`OperationalError`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/operationalerror.html):

```
model.readUserAddresses(email)
  .then(ifFalseThrow(Promise.OperationalError))
  .then(prepDbCustomer)
  .then(shopify.customerCreate)
  .error(() => false)
```

---

If that doesn't fit your needs (e.g. because the `OperationalError` already is used for something else), you actually don't have to make it a custom error type (subclass) at all. [`catch`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) also takes plain predicate functions, so you could something like

```
model.readUserAddresses(email)
  .then(ifFalseThrow(Error, "noUserFound"))
  .then(prepDbCustomer)
  .then(shopify.customerCreate)
  .catch(e => e.message == "noUserFound", () => false)
```

---

And last but not least, throwing exceptions is not the best idea if all you want is to skip a part of your chain. Rather branch explicitly:

```
model.readUserAddresses(email)
  .then(userAddresses =>
     userAddresses
       ? prepDbCustomer(userAddresses)
         .then(shopify.customerCreate)
       : false
  )
```

(and shorten that callback at your discretion, e.g. `.then(u => u && prepDbCustomer(u).then(shopify.customerCreate))`)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this.

```
model.readUserAddresses(email)
.then((status) => {
    if(!status) {
        var error = new Error('No user Found');
        error.customMessage = 'customMessage';
        error.name = 'customeName';
        throw error;
    }
})
.then(prepDbCustomer)
.then(shopify.customerCreate)
.catch((err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

I would recommend creating a customeError object to handle errors instead.

Comment: OP alread *is* creating custom errors (of class `NoUserFound`)?

Comment: Well since the OP is hesitant of creating a custom error `NoUserFound` Class I thought this could be a possible way of handling a error. To be honest I would suggest that he stick to customeError Classes.